# it induces a surjective map $(A/J(A))^\times \to (B/J(B))^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose one has a surjective algebra homomorphism $f: A \to B$. It induces a surjective algebra homomorphism $f': A/J(A) \to B/J(B)$. Then the author goes on to prove that this homomorphism $f'$ splits, and he concludes that "HENCE, it induces a surjective map $(A/J(A))^\times \to (B/J(B))^\times$".

My question is that why we need splitness to get a surjective map between invertible elements. Is this map a bijective one since kernel elements cannot be invertible. Thank you!

Comment: The kernel of $A^\times \to B^\times$ is the inverse image of $1$ in $A^\times$, it is not the kernel of $A\to B$ which is the inverse image of $0$ in $A$.

Comment: If a ring homomorphism $u : R \to S$ is split surjective, then there is a ring homomorphism $v : S \to R$ such that $u \circ v = \operatorname{id}_R$. Thus, the corresponding restrictions $u^\times : R^\times \to S^\times$ and $v^\times : S^\times \to R^\times$ to the groups of invertible elements will satisfy $u^\times \circ v^\times = \left(u\circ v\right)^\times = \operatorname{id}_R^\times = \operatorname{id}_{R^\times}$. This shows that $u^\times$. This argument really relies on the **split** surjectivity of $u$ (and not just as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map, but as a ring homomorphism).

Comment: Darij is right, but while splitting is sufficient for the surjection on units, it is not necessary: consider the projection map $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Hello! Angina! I mean the kernel elements of $f'$ cannot be invertible. So the invertibles all come from $A/J(A)$ \kerf, and there is a bijection between $A/J(A)$ \kerf and B. So the invertibles will form a bijection. Is this reasoning right?

Comment: There are examples when it is not a bijection....

Comment: But f' splits surjective, so by the isomorphism theorem, $A/J(A)/kerf \cong B/J(B)$. I am totally lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose $f':A'\to B'$ is a ring homomorphism which splits in the sense
that there is a ring homomorphism $g:B'\to A'$ with $f'\circ g$ the identity on $B'$.

If $b\in B'^\times$ then $g(b)\in A'^\times$ and so $b=f'(g(b))\in f'(A'^\times)$.
Therefore $b\in f'(A^\times)$.